# How can I use Session Variables to output login username

Tags: php, session

I'm building an application and have just added a Login page which works well, communicating with a "username" and "password" field in the database. After logging in, it takes you a page users are authorized to see.

Is there a way I can display "Welcome, xxx" to the particular user logged in at the next page? And more importantly, output detailed information of the logged in user on that next page? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to temporarily store the data which can be seen across the page....
After checking successful login credential, You can stores the user data in session

```
<?php
     session_start();     
     $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;
    ?>
```

After storing the user data in session,you can now access those data across the different pages until you unset those session data

```
<?php 
session_start();     
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   echo 'Welcome, '.$_SESSION['username']; 
} else {
echo 'Sorry, You are not logged in.';
}
?>
```

When user get logged out,unregister those session variable. Unregistering of session variable can be done in following way:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without using Session Variables, because my site only has 2 pages?

Comment: That is, get the username of the person logged in and display it on the other page.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use session?

Comment: I have this on my webpage 
<?php 
session_start();     
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   echo 'Welcome, '.$_SESSION['username']; 
} else {
echo 'Sorry, You are not logged in.';
}
?>

And I'm trying to add the
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
?>

As you suggested, but apparently I can't have two session starts on the page. Help, please.

Comment: Put <?php session_start(); unset($_SESSION['username']); ?> in logout page.....If you want to auto start session, enable session.auto_start  in php.ini file...

Answer (score 0):

Just verify the session and call the corresponding user from the database. Suppose you are using username in a session

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'USERNAME';
```

So you will just run a query to call the username and other information from database using mysql queries like

```
$user =$_SESSION['loggedin'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE user = '$user'");
```

This is just an example.I recommend using salt and encrypting your sessions and then call the queries.Also use mysqli /PDO as mysql is deprecated.Above one was just for example

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about PHP session where you can put username in session like this

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

which can be used on subsequent page request till you logout.

Comment: I have, yes, but wouldn't that have to be equal to the variable storing the Username value?

Comment: Yes that will be something like $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;

Comment: I tried that, but shouldn't $user_name have to be declared first and specified that it relates to the User_name field in the database?

Comment: That is very true first declare and define $username = "your value"; then do $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I don't mean to sound thick, but my value isn't constant, it equals who the logged in person is, which could be many of the usernames in the database.

Answer (score 0):

yes sure you can do this. I hope when u check the valid username and password, you set the username or userdetail in session variable. If you have set the variable you can always print that session variable. Make sure you have started the session at the beginning of the page.

eg if you have set

```
$_SESSION['user'] = 'Ram';
```

you can simply print

```
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```